# Tomcat 9 logging with log4j

Tags: log, tomcat

Hello i want to configure the logging in Tomcat 9.
I was following a tutorial about using log4j1.x.
Seems that part relative to log4j is gone since Tomcat9.
Im following this instructions taken from the book Tomcat 7 Essentials ( chapter 6 Logging in Tomcat 7).

How to use log4j
Following are the steps to be performed to use log4j:

1. Download apache-log4j-1.2.X.tar.gz from its official URL http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html , where X is the minor version.
2. Unzip the folder and place the log4j.jar in the lib for TOMCAT_HOME/lib
   and delete the juli*.jar from lib .
3. Delete the logging.properties from the TOMCAT_HOME/CONF .
4. Create a file log4j.properties in the TOMCAT_HOME/CONF and define the
   log appenders for the Tomcat instance. The following screenshot shows the
   appenders for catalina.out . Also, the highlighted code shows the roll-over
   of logs per day:

[image]

But it doesnt work, i got an error in Tomcat9 and is not even started. The error doesnt explain much, only Tomcat error cant be launch.

Tomcat was working ok since the above modifications.

So i cant find any documentation adapted to tomcat9 ( i suppose some tweaks could be necessary), or the equivalent config file in log4j2 ( and any changes needed to use log4j2 instead of log4j1).

Summarising id need to use the tutorial for tomcat7 adapted to tomcat9 if possible with log4j1 and if is not possible to adapt or tweak to do the same using log4j2

Any help would be apreciated.